# Not able to remove the ionic filter

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic filter, When I click the cancel button in filter bar I am able to remove the filter but when I want to do that automatically without clicking the cancel button when shifting tabs I am  not able to do that.

```
// code in angular controller for initializing the filter
var filterBarInstance;    
filterBarInstance = $ionicFilterBar.show({
 });

 // when I shift tabs I am calling the below method to close the modal of the filter(if the modal is opened)   
filterBarInstance = $ionicFilterBar.show({
  cancel : '',
     });
```

I am calling the above methods whcih are present in the filter directive but that method is not getting triggered. Kindly , use the url https://github.com/djett41/ionic-filter-bar/blob/master/js/ionic.filter.bar.directive.js and provide me some solutions to fix this.

Comment: Asking people to download your app to help troubleshoot it isn't going to happen.  Need to provide more code in the question and tell us what the error you're getting is so we can help.

Comment: @Jeff: Ok I apologize now I have updated my code and provided the url of the directive for the filter which I am using in my application.

Comment: @Jeff: why you didnt remove the negetive vote , I have updated my query.

Comment: @Jeff kindly remove my downvote

Comment: I still don't feel like you've provided enough information to get an answer.  For one thing, all of the relevant code should be placed in the question, not a link.  You should explain what you've tried and what error you are getting. There's still just a link with 160 lines of code to dig through.  Make a JS fiddle so we can see what you're trying to do. Anyway, I removed the downvote for you I hope you find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

try `filterBarInstance()`

I hope that solve your problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11534233)

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to give solution